# wrong column name with eloquent relationship

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to retreive notifications table from user but I get this error:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'notifications.user_id' in
> 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `notifications` where
> `notifications`.`user_id` = 1 and `notifications`.`user_id` is not
> null) (View:
> C:\xampp\laravelprojects\DreamingEye\resources\views\components\navbar.blade.php

It's for this code:

```
<a class="@if(!auth()->user()->notification->read_at)px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-sm font-semibold @endif" href="{{ route('notifications.index') }}">Notifications</a>
```

The column is called notifications. I have no idea why the user_id is there.

The user model:

```
public function notification()
        {
            return $this->hasMany(Notifications::class);
        }
```

The notification model is currently empty

The notification table:

```
{
        Schema::create('notifications', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('id')->primary();
            $table->string('type');
            $table->morphs('notifiable');
            $table->text('data');
            $table->timestamp('read_at')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: do you have column user_id  in notifications table ? so better add notifications tabel structure.  user_id  is used to map relationship

Comment: @JohnLobo I don't have a user_id there

Comment: @JohnLobo notifiable_type and notifiable_id

Comment: i missunderstood your questions .its laravle notifications table

Comment: @JohnLobo yes but I think it uses data row

Comment: @JohnLobo I'm getting this in the data row when liking and it's correct: {"user_id":2,"post_id":2}

Comment: i havent used database based notifications so just google it .or some one might help you

Comment: @JohnLobo thanks anyway though, I appreaciate the help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234661/discussion-between-john-lobo-and-shanediesel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to define relationship manually. So you can do

```
@foreach(auth()->user->notifications as $notification)

<a class="@if($notification->read_at) px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-sm font-semibold @endif" href="{{ route('notifications.index') }}">Notifications</a>
@endforeach
```

Also you can use

```
$notification->read()
```

To get notifications relationship,In user model used `Notifiable` Trait and it calls `HasDatabaseNotifications` Trait which defined

```
trait HasDatabaseNotifications
{
    /**
     * Get the entity's notifications.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphMany
     */
    public function notifications()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(DatabaseNotification::class, 'notifiable')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
    }

    /**
     * Get the entity's read notifications.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder
     */
    public function readNotifications()
    {
        return $this->notifications()->read();
    }

    /**
     * Get the entity's unread notifications.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder
     */
    public function unreadNotifications()
    {
        return $this->notifications()->unread();
    }
}
```

Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/notifications#accessing-the-notifications